# Java: How to return the String result of all the methods in a class from a single variable?

Tags: java

I want to return the result (which is in String format) of all the methods of a class and assign it a variable.

For example:

```
public class test()
   {
      public String result;
      public method1(){
        result = value1;
        return value;
       }
      public method2(){
        result = value2;
        return "efg";
       }
```

Now if I print result it should be like below:

`value1 + value2`

i.e., concatenated String.

Is this possible? If yes, can you please tell me how?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create another method which adds both methods return value and returns the concatenated result.

```
public String method() {
   return method1() + method2();
}
```

Assuming both methods return something.

**method1:**

```
public String method1(){
   return value1;
}
```

**method2:**

```
public String method2(){
   return value2;
}
```

> Note: Return type in must in methods

Comment: Is there any better solution, because I have more than 150 methods?

Comment: @ManjunathChinnanagoudar Why do you have more than 150 methods? Please post it as a separate question. I can't tell anything from that. You might not even need 150+ methods in the first place.

Comment: It is a Page object model of the web page. In POM we are supposed to create a method for each field. So for 150+ fields, I have to write 150+ methods

Comment: @ManjunathChinnanagoudar You means getters? What does those function do? Anyways have to tried storing them  in an arraylist or something?